# Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.AppendMySiteToUrl(System.String)'

Tags: error, patching

We are using SP2013 on-premise enterprise edition.
Recently our servers have been patched with various windows update (not SharePoint cumulative update). After then when browse to the MySite Web Host thru WFE1 it will return error

> Method not found: 'System.String
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.AppendMySiteToUrl(System.String)'.

However, when browse thru WFE2 there is no problem. I compared the "Installed Window update" for both WFE and seems the same. What else I could check? Any experience on above error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although all the servers "Installed Window update" shows patches were installed, it is not fully propagated in SharePoint binary.

By checking in Central Administration > Upgrade and Migration > **Check Product and patch installation status** (/_admin/PatchStatus.aspx), I found our WFE1 and APP1 contains some updates **Missing/Required** highlighted in red color.

Notice that even there is only single KB number (e.g. KB2881061) it contains multiple minor fixes towards different services. In my case, update is success in most area but missed in WFE1 and APP1's User Profiles.

We run the patch installer again. Then run the Product Configuration Manager in all servers. Finally the patch level for all servers are in sync and the titled error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

On the impacted FE, run:

`psconfig -cmd applicationcontent`

Reference:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093%28v=office.14%29.aspx